guizero update complete gui
I have written a small app using guizero.
It consist of a single Window (app) with a menu, some labels and text fields.
Now I would like to make it multilingual and created a dict with a list as values.
translation = {
    "Connections": ["Verbindungsliste\n\n", "Connections\n\n"],
    "Select file": ["Datei auswählen", "Select file"],

The list is indexed by the language number and if I init these number the gui works fine in the defined language.
GERMAN = 0
ENGLISH = 1

language = ENGLISH


But if I update the language by a menu call nothing happens.
def menu_language_german():
    global language
    language = GERMAN
    app.update()

def menu_language_english():
    global language
    language = ENGLISH
    app.update()


What do I have to do, to update the whole GUI?
I have tried the same with a window, but the result was the same - nothing.
Now i have found out what the update() method is for.
If you have something like:
textfield.value = "write this"
some_long_running_calculation()
textfield.value = "write that"

"write this" will never be displayed, except it is followed by app.update().
For the moment i found a workaround by passing a command line parameter to my script, which works well.
Later i'll try to use a hidden app and windows, which i can destroy and recreate.
